# Ignore invalid self-signed ssl certificate warning in Grunt

Tags: ssl, gruntjs, warnings, self-signed

I'm using Grunt with grunt-nwabap-ui5uploader plugin to deploy an application to NW ABAP server, I have written a upload task in Gruntfile and trying to execute it, but having an error about self signed certificate, which aborts the task. I have tried to use option --force to ignore the warning but it seems that this task isn't executed:

```
>     Running "nwabap_ui5uploader:upload_webapp" (nwabap_ui5uploader) task
>     Warning: Error: self signed certificate (undefined) Used --force, continuing.
>     
>     Done, but with warnings.
```

Is there a way to ignore this warning and execute the task anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Actually found a solution:

Set the useStrictSSL mode option to false in Gruntfile upload task.
https://github.com/pfefferf/grunt-nwabap-ui5uploader#optionsconnusestrictssl